# Como actualizar una tabla, obteniendo información desde un control SELECT

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax, select

soy nuevo en este foro y me encuentro actualmente en un dilema, ya que necesito programar una pagina donde se exhiban todos los registros ingresados a una base de datos MYSQL, al iniciar la página se despliegan todos los registros, pero tambien se me pide poder filtrar los datos que se muestran en la tabla, los filtros son : 1- por año 2- por mes 3- por semestre.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para no hacer demasiada extensa esta consulta, me centraré en el primer filtro que es AÑO, si logro resolver como filtrar por AÑOS lograré programar los demas filros, por ello adjunto el código del control de selección "año" a continuación.
[image: Código del selector]

Lo que necesito saber es que puedo hacer para que cuando ocurra un cambio en el selector de año; se actualize la tabla y muestre el año que ha sido seleccionado solamente.
Si pudisesen ayudarme con algo de código sería genial, de ante mano gracias a todos.

Comment: Deberias de agregar tu codigo y lo que has intentado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes utilizar un evento change de jquery el cual te toma el valor del año seleccionado, y después enviarlo por ajax para realizar la consulta y te regresa los datos filtrados

```
 $(document).on('change', '#cboAnio', function(event){
        var valAnio=$(this).find("option:selected").val();
        //peticion ajax
        $.ajax({                                      
        url: "consulta.php"
        type: 'POST',
        data: {Anio:valAnio},
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(res){
            if(res.error==0){//puedes regresar un valor de error pos si ocurre 
                $('#'+view_result).html(res.view_result);//contenedor
            }

        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 

        }
        });
    });
```

otra opción para para que se le aplique a todos los filtros seria de la siguiente manera:
pon tus elementos de filtrado dentro de un formulario

```
<form id="idform">
///tus distintos filtros como anio, mes
</form>
 $(document).on('change', '#idform', function(event){

       var formData=new FormData(this);
        //peticion ajax
       $.ajax({                                      
        url: "consulta.php"

        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(res){//res trae el resultado de tu backend en json

        }
       });
});
```

en tu archivo consulta.php

```
<?php 
//$_POST["anio"] accede a la variable como lo pasaste por ajax
$anio=$_POST["anio"];
$con_sol="SELECT * FROM solicitud where YEAR(fec_act_ini) =$anio" ;
$exeSol=mysql_query($con_sol);
$htmlTabla="";
while ($fila = mysql_fetch_assoc($exeSol)) {
   $htmlTabla.="<tr><td>".$fila['Id']."</td><td>".$fila['FechaInicio']."</td></tr>";

}

$respuesta=array("error"=>0,"view_result"=>$htmlTabla);
echo json_encode($respuesta);
?>
```

Comment: Amigo disculpa mi ignorancia, este código que me facilitaste debo insertarlo sobre la misma pagina que contiene el codigo de la tabla o debo crear pagina .js y meter este codigo ?

Comment: lo recomendable es colocarlo en un archivo js pero también puede ir sobre la misma pagina si es que lo acepta